# How to set different destinations in nodejs using multer?

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm trying to upload any file using **[Multer package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer)**. It's working fine when I use following code in my `server.js` file.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    multer = require('multer');
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(multer({
        dest: './static/uploads/',
        rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
            return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        }
    }));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

app.post('/api/upload', function (req, res) {
    res.send({image: true, file: req.files.userFile.originalname, savedAs: req.files.userFile.name});
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

What I want is to store file at different locations. I had tried following code but it does not work for me.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    multer = require('multer');
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(multer({
        //dest: './static/uploads/',
        rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
            return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        }
    }));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
});

app.post('/api/pdf', function (req, res) {
    app.use(multer({ dest: './static/pdf/'}));
    res.send({image: true, file: req.files.userFile.originalname, savedAs: req.files.userFile.name});
});

app.post('/api/image', function (req, res) {
    app.use(multer({ dest: './static/image/'}));
    res.send({image: true, file: req.files.userFile.originalname, savedAs: req.files.userFile.name});
});

app.post('/api/video', function (req, res) {
    app.use(multer({ dest: './static/video/'}));
    res.send({image: true, file: req.files.userFile.originalname, savedAs: req.files.userFile.name});
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Means, if I hit `http://localhost:3000/api/pdf` file should store at 'pdf' folder, if I hit `http://localhost:3000/api/video` file should store at 'video' folder.

Is there any way to achieve this aim?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's not possible with 'multer' as of now. https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/58 this is the reply which I got from 'owner'.

Comment: Solved - https://github.com/jpfluger/multer/blob/examples/multer-upload-files-to-different-directories.md

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update**

Quite a few things have changed since I posted the original answer.

With `multer 1.2.1`.

1. You need to use `DiskStorage` to specify *where* & *how* of the stored file.
2. By default, multer will use the operating system's default directory. In our case, since we are particular about the location. We need to ensure that the folder exists before we could save the file over there.

> Note: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing destination as a function.

More [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage)

```
'use strict';

let multer = require('multer');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
      let type = req.params.type;
      let path = `./uploads/${type}`;
      fs.mkdirsSync(path);
      callback(null, path);
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
      //originalname is the uploaded file's name with extn
      callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
  })
});

app.post('/api/:type', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send();
});
```

`fs-extra` for creating directory, [just in case if it doesn't exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra#mkdirsdir-callback)

**Original answer**

You can use [changeDest](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#changedestdest-req-res).

> Function to rename the directory in which to place uploaded files.

It is available from [v0.1.8](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/58#issuecomment-75315556)

```
app.post('/api/:type', multer({
dest: './uploads/',
changeDest: function(dest, req, res) {
    var newDestination = dest + req.params.type;
    var stat = null;
    try {
        stat = fs.statSync(newDestination);
    } catch (err) {
        fs.mkdirSync(newDestination);
    }
    if (stat && !stat.isDirectory()) {
        throw new Error('Directory cannot be created because an inode of a different type exists at "' + dest + '"');
    }
    return newDestination
}
}), function(req, res) {
     //set your response
});
```

Comment: is there any way to add date ??

Answer (score 10):

Multer is a middleware so you can pass it like this :

```
app.post('/test/route', multer({...options...}), module.someThing)
```

or

```
app.post('/test/route', multer({...options...}), function(req, res){
........some code ......
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a function like so:

```
var uploadFnct = function(dest){
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, './public/img/'+dest+'/');
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                var datetimestamp = Date.now();
                cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1]);
            }
        });

        var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                        storage: storage
                    }).single('file');

        return upload;
    };
```

And then use it in your upload route:

```
//Handle the library upload
    app.post('/app/library/upload', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
        var currUpload = uploadFnct('library');
        currUpload(req,res,function(err){
            if(err){
                 res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
                 return;
            }
            res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null, filename: req.file.filename});
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing `destination` as a function. When passing a string, multer will make sure that the directory is created for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions shown here but nothing helped me.

ChangeDest attr is not available anymore (As Sridhar proposes in his answer)

I want to share my solution (I am using express 4.13 and multer 1.2):

**Imports**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var multer  = require('multer');
```

**Storage variable** (see documentation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage))

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        var dest = 'uploads/' + req.params.type;
        var stat = null;
        try {
            stat = fs.statSync(dest);
        } catch (err) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dest);
        }
        if (stat && !stat.isDirectory()) {
            throw new Error('Directory cannot be created because an inode of a different type exists at "' + dest + '"');
        }       
        cb(null, dest);
    }
});
```

**Initializing Multer:**

```
var upload = multer(
    { 
        dest: 'uploads/',
        storage: storage
    }
);
```

**Using it!**

```
router.use("/api/:type", upload.single("obj"));
router.post('/api/:type', controllers.upload_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (req.path.match('/pdf')) {
      cb(null,<destination>)
    }
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  }
})
```

This works in case, the path is unique. You can modify (checking for the end point {req.path}) according to your needs. Though this solution is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

we can get path as

```
 const basePath=`${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/public/uploads/`;
```