# How to change directory. Multer/express.js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have two form like this

```
<form action="/createFolder" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="folder" id="year" placeholder="enter year">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="student" placeholder="enter your name">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="filedata" />
    <input type="file" name="filedata" />
    <input type="file" name="filedata" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
```

in  the first one user enter data and my node.js script create two folders like this "year/name"

```
app.post('/createFolder', upload.none(), (req, res, next) => {
 const body = req.body;
 if (fs.existsSync(body.folder)) {
    console.log('Folder exist');
 } else {
    fs.mkdirSync(body.folder);
 }
 fs.mkdirSync(body.folder + '/' + body.name);
 updateStorageConfig(body.folder, body.name);
 res.redirect("/");
```

In the **updateStorageConfig** function i try to set **multer.diskStorage()** and then create app.post for my second form like this

```
function updateStorageConfig(folder, name) {
storageConfig = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, folder + '/' + name);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

upd = (multer({storage: storageConfig}).array("filedata", 3));
app.post("/upload", upd, function (req, res, next) {
    let filedata = req.files;
    if(!filedata)
        res.send("Error");
    else {
        res.end();
    }
});
```

If i create the fist folders its work ok, but when i create another folders, files from second form downloads in old direction.

How change the direction??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set different destinations in nodejs using multer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698176/how-to-set-different-destinations-in-nodejs-using-multer)

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi no, it doesn't. I already have code like in this example. When I create new folder I need to replace old directory to new in function updateStorageConfig. Because right now my cod do something like this: 
1. I create first couple of folders and upload file right here
2. I create another couple of folders and my code upload file in old directory, in first couple